# Use template template class argument as parameter

Tags: c++, templates

Modern C++ Design gives the following example:

```
template <class T> struct EnsureNotNull
{
    static void Check(T*& ptr)
    {
      if (!ptr) ptr = GetDefaultValue();
    }
};

template
<
   class T,
   template <class> class CheckingPolicy = EnsureNotNull,
   template <class> class ThreadingModel
>
class SmartPtr
  : public CheckingPolicy<T>
  , public ThreadingModel<SmartPtr>
{
...
  T* operator->()
  {
    typename ThreadingModel<SmartPtr>::Lock guard(*this);
    CheckingPolicy<T>::Check(pointee_);
    return pointee_;
  }
private:
  T* pointee_;
};
```

I couldn't figure how ThreadingModel template would be constructed in a fashion that It could accept SmartPtr as parameter, in my mind some crazy recursion is going to happen. How can this be possible?

**Edit:**

I've tried Potatoswatter (sorry lol) comment:

```
template <class SmartPtr> struct SingleThreadingModel
{
  class Lock
  {
    public: 
      Lock(SmartPtr&)
      {
      }
  };
};
```

but it did'nt worked.

here is the error that gcc is giving me:

```
main.cpp:28:35: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class> class ThreadingModel’
main.cpp:28:35: error:   expected a type, got ‘SmartPtr’
```

Comment: Ah, yes.  Template template parameters.  One of the most confusing things ever.

Comment: Your new code looks fine. What error do you get, and where? Also, a Tomatoswatter sounds like it would make a big mess, which I try to avoid doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to pass `SmartPtr` as a template *type* argument to `ThreadingModel`. `SmartPtr` however is a template, not a concrete type, and the [injected class-name](http://books.google.de/books?id=EotSAwuBkJoC&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=c%2B%2B+injected+class-name&source=bl&ots=iwOYJ9_hgh&sig=7-6UMoMHZctldpOYPvDucV4bXE8&hl=de&ei=YMRkTLuvEeacOLC4gKoK&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=c%2B%2B%20injected%20class-name&f=false) is not available in the inheritance list.

Also note that you can't just use default arguments for template parameters in arbitrary positions (*§14.1/11*):

> If a template-parameter has a default template-argument, all subsequent template-parameters shall have a default template-argument supplied.

Your code with those issues fixed:

```
template
<
  class T,
  template <class> class ThreadingModel,
  template <class> class CheckingPolicy = EnsureNotNull
>
class SmartPtr
  : public CheckingPolicy<T>
  , public ThreadingModel<SmartPtr<T, ThreadingModel, CheckingPolicy> > 
//                         ^ .... now passing a concrete class .... ^
{
    T* operator->() {
        // the following use of SmartPtr is fine as it is the injected class-name:
        typename ThreadingModel<SmartPtr>::Lock guard(*this);
        // ...
    }
};
```

Note that while *Modern C++ Design* is an excellent book, it can't replace a good basic book on templates like [Vandevoorde/Josuttis](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/).

Comment: Makes sense. I've downloaded the source code from Loki and noticed that ThreadingModel isn't present on the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

The recursion is OK because passing a specialization as a template parameter does not directly cause it to be instantiated.

(`ThreadingModel<SmartPtr>` in the base list is just shorthand for `ThreadingModel< SmartPtr< T, CheckingPolicy, ThreadingModel > >` which uses the "current specialization.")

I don't know what `ThreadingModel` is supposed to do, so I can't implement it, but it should have a declaration of the form

```
template< class Client > class MyThreading
```

and it cannot access anything inside `Client` outside of `MyThreading` member functions. If you use `Client` and `Client` depends on `MyThreading`, then infinite recursion does happen.

Comment: Potato, could you provide how the declaration of ThreadingModel Could be implemented? I've tried many ways here and none worked.

Comment: hmmm, tried that. It didn't worked using or not using Client insite class. Note that on the example it builds a guard passing this as parameter so it should work.