# Confusing template code

Tags: c++, templates

What does the below mean

```
template < template < template < class > class, class > class Param >
```

I never used `template <template <X>>` kind of syntax

Got it off of another [website](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=11061947)

```
template < template < template < class > class, class > class Param >
struct Bogus {


int foo() {
printf("ok\n");;
}
};
```

Appreciate any light on this syntax. Thank you

Update: Looks like there were some explanations already existing, please refer to Jerry's solution below

Comment: New C++11 syntax for templates. See links posted below.

Comment: @AJG85: new C++11 syntax? Really?

Comment: Oh just did some googling. New to me I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called a template template parameter. It's been discussed a number of times before:

[Syntax of C++ Template Template Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282971/syntax-of-c-template-template-parameters)
[What are some uses of template template parameters in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters-in-c)
[Use template template class argument as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472295/use-template-template-class-argument-as-parameter)

etc.

Comment: so much stuff in C++, I keep learning and more stuff keeps showing up :D. hope there was a bible. Thanks Jerry

Answer (score 3):

There are three ontological tiers in C++: *values*, *types* and *templates*.

A template instantiation is a type. An object *is* of a certain type, and it *has* a value.

All three sorts of entities can appear as template parameters:

```
template <int N, typename T, template <typename> C>
{
  C<T> array[N];
};
```

The parameter are classified, in this order, as "non-type template parameter", "template parameter", and "template template parameter" (I think).

Having template parameters can be very useful, for example if you want to allow something to be parametrized on arbitrary containers (especially with variadic templates!):

```
template <typename T, template <typename...> Container>
void print(const Container<T> & c)
{ /* ... */ }
```

Incidentally, when a class template contains members, you have to use the words `typename` and `template`, respectively to address them according to their nature (saying nothing means you want to refer to a *value*):

```
template <typename T> struct Foo
{
  T value;
  typedef T * pointer;
  template <typename S> struct Nested;
};

// now refer to them as:
Foo<T>::value;
typename Foo<T>::pointer;
template<typename S> Foo<T>::template Nested<S>;
```